Display multiples pictures in the same ImageView using Glide
I have only one imageView and a multiples url of pictures, I want to display every loaded picture in this imageView using Glide.
I use this code with a loop but it displays only the first picture, I tried .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE) but it's not working, also using .setImageDrawable(null) in imageView not working
 for (link in response.body() as MutableList<String>) {
            Glide.with(MainActivity@this).load(link)
           .into(imgDownloaded)
                    }   

